# Transforming DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here' a question on transforming a DataFrame. After creating a DataFrame from a pivot table and applying .unstack(), I came up with a table like this

```
         Amount
Color    Red    Yellow   Blue    Green
Date
2006-01  56     41       15      10
2006-01  51     23       26      36
2006-01  36     54       15      43
```

Now, my question: How can I delete the rows/columns "Amount" and "Color" above the main index ("Date")? This is what I need:

```
         Red    Yellow   Blue    Green
Date
2006-01  56     41       15      10
2006-01  51     23       26      36
2006-01  36     54       15      43
```

Also, it would be good to know how to rename the index "Date" as I have to merge two tables where in one case the time is named "Date" and in the other "Close Date".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of your top-level columns by just selecting the one top-level column value:

```
df = df["Amount"]
```

`Color` isn't the name of a column - it's the name of the row of column names.  If you don't want your column levels to have names, you can set them to `None`:

```
df.columns.names = [None]
```

If you haven't gotten rid of the top-level column, you'll have to set `df.columns.names = [None, None]` since there will still be two levels of column names.